# mouseEntered is not working

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have an array of 5 `JLabel` objects and I have added mouse listener to all of them, in `mouseEntered()` function I am making the label opaque(true) to change its background color, but this code is not working properly, please help.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class A extends MouseAdapter {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[5];

    A() {
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            label[i] = new JLabel("LABEL: "+i);
            label[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            label[i].addMouseListener(this);
            frame.add(label[i]);
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
                new A();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent entered) {
        if(entered.getSource().equals(label))
            ((JLabel)entered.getComponent()).setOpaque(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you explain specifically what currently happens, rather than saying it "doesn't work".

Answer (score 2):

The likely cause is `if(entered.getSource().equals(label))`

The source of the event will never be the `label` array, but will be one of it's elements.  A better condition might be `if(entered.getSource() instanceof JLabel)`

And you'll also need `entered.getComponent().repaint();` after you change the opacity property of the label